# CSS not overwriting properties correctly

Tags: css

From what I've read `css` styles overwrite each other depending on the order of inclusion. But I'm experiencing some strange behavior, shown in the picture:

[image]

It is clearly visible that `default.css` is included after `base.css` which would suppose that styles from `default.css` will overwrite styles from `base.css`. However this is not the case, as you see, the style from `base.css` persists and the style from `default.css` is being cancelled out. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because CSS class selectors (e.g., `.marginblock` in your example) has a higher precedence than CSS type selectors (`body` in your example).

If your CSS were as follows, you would have the behavior you expect:

In `base.css`:

```
.marginblock {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

In `default.css`:

```
.marginblock {
    margin: 25px;
}
```

Here's more detail on the CSS order of precedence:

1. ID selectors
2. Attribute selectors
3. Class selectors
4. Child selectors
5. Adjacent sibling selectors
6. Descendant selectors
7. Type selectors

More information can be found [here](http://www.alternategateways.com/tutorials/css/css-101/part-four-the-css-order-of-precedence).

Answer (score 1):

Your style from default.css has a more specific selector so will overwrite the base.css style.  You may want to google how specificity points work in determining how css gets applied.